# How to found top error from GrayLog stream wise?

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I want to setup a mechanism to pull a daily report which will send us top 10 errors(stream wise) from GrayLog Server.

I think we can do via gray log api interface but i am not sure which API end points needs to be called for the same.

Can someone please help on this with some example ?

P.S. If you see that this question shouldn't be posted on stack overflow because it doesn't contains any code snippets then Moderators please move to the right place. Thanks

Comment: i don't think as of now Graylog provide any such method. So we achieved this  by firing direct query on Graylog's elastic search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think as of now Graylog provide any such method. So we achieved this by firing direct query on Graylog's elastic search.

or you can take a look at [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)